# Can you pull in excludes/includes options in Typescript Compiler API?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying use the Typescript API to do some custom compilation (using plugins, etc.).

When compiling with the command line, typescript will automatically take into account not only the compilerOptions, but also the `excludes` key, as well as the `types` key (among other things).

The Typescript API documentation is almost non-existent, but I've tried manually doing a deep search and excluding these files from the total file list passed into the `createProgram` method. However, this has taken a toll on our build performance, and I think the Typescript compiler has a much more efficient solution.

Here's what I have in my `compile.ts` file.

```
import ts from 'typescript';
import keysTransformer from 'ts-transformer-keys/transformer';
import tsConfig from './tsconfig.json';
import fs from 'fs';

const deepFindTsFiles = (dir: string, fileList?: string[]) => {
    dir = dir.endsWith('/') ? dir : dir + '/'
    const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    fileList = fileList || [];
    files.forEach((file) => {
        console.log('file', dir + file);
        console.log(tsConfig.exclude.includes(dir + file));
        if (fs.statSync(dir + file).isDirectory() && !tsConfig.exclude.includes(dir + file)) {
            fileList = deepFindTsFiles(dir + file + '/', fileList);
        }
        else if (!tsConfig.exclude.includes(dir + file) && file.split('.')[1].includes('ts')) {
            fileList!.push(dir + file);
        }
    });
    return fileList;
};

const fileList = deepFindTsFiles(tsConfig.compilerOptions.rootDir);

// the compiler options parsed from tsconfig.json
const { options } = ts.parseJsonConfigFileContent(
    tsConfig,
    ts.sys,
    __dirname
);

// createProgram doesn't seem to have an option for excludes/includes/types
const program = ts.createProgram(fileList, options);

const transformers = {
    before: [keysTransformer(program)],
    after: []
};

program.emit(undefined, undefined, undefined, false, transformers);
```

The code above properly compiles my source code and applies the proper plugins, however it's much slower than using the command line tools.

What's passed into the `createProgram` method is *just* the compilerOptions object in my tsconfig.json file, *not* the files to exclude. It does not seem like the `createProgram` method takes any arguments like this.

But, surely there is? Right? I have to imagine that this is possible. But, the documentation is severely lacking

Comment: It's all inside `parseJsonConfigFileContent` which returns, among other stuff, [`fileNames`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts#L2058) which it seems to collect based on `"files"`, `"include"` and `"exclude"` in json. It uses [`matchFileNames`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts#L2646) which in turn uses `readDirectory` of `ParseConfigHost`, which actually is implemented in `sys`: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/sys.ts#L1220

Comment: Ok; so, just to make sure I understand, the `fileNames` key in the object returned from `parseJsonConfigFileContent` should have a list of the file names with the excluded and included files taken into account? So, instead of creating my own list of file names, I can use that instead?

Answer (score 6):

I managed to figure out how to get the list of fileNames using the tsconfig.json and the TS compiler API.

```
const configPath = ts.findConfigFile(
  "./", /*searchPath*/ 
  ts.sys.fileExists,
  "tsconfig.json"
);

if (!configPath) throw new Error("Could not find a valid 'tsconfig.json'.");

const configFile = ts.readJsonConfigFile(configPath, ts.sys.readFile);

const { fileNames } = ts.parseJsonSourceFileConfigFileContent(
  configFile,
  ts.sys,
  './'
);

console.log(fileNames)
```

This takes into account the includes and excludes specified in the tsconfig.json.
This might not be the best way to do this but I have been struggling to figure this out for a while.

Comment: thanks for sharing this example! A small correction, the base path for `parseJsonSourceFileConfigFileContent` must be absolute and ending in `/`. If there is an error it doesn't throw exception but fills the `errors` property in the result. If `fileNames` is empty, check the `errors` and the base path.